# unused expression

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

Newbie here.  In the following code:

```
+ (NSString *)descriptionOfProgram:(id)program
{
    NSMutableArray *mutableCopyOfProgram = [program mutableCopy];
    NSString *descr = @"";
    for (int i=0; i<mutableCopyOfProgram.count; i++)
    {
        descr = [descr stringByAppendingString:(@"%@",[mutableCopyOfProgram objectAtIndex:i])];
    }
    return descr;
}
```

I keep getting an "expression result unused" warning on the code in the loop.  But how can that be, when in the next line I return the expression result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning you get is because you should use `stringByAppendingFormat:` method instead of `stringByAppendingString:`. Anyway, I would recommend using `NSMutableString` for building a string. Also, it's better to use `[mutableCopyOfProgram count]` instead of `mutableCopyOfProgram.count`. The following code should work for you:

```
+ (NSString *)descriptionOfProgram:(id)program
{
    NSMutableArray *mutableCopyOfProgram = [program mutableCopy];
    NSMutableString *descr = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i < [mutableCopyOfProgram count]; i++)
    {
        [descr appendFormat:@"%@", [mutableCopyOfProgram objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    return descr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much--I appreciate it.  A newbie question:  how/why are NSMutableString and [mutableCopyOfProgram count] more appropriate than NSString and mutableCopyOfProgram.count in this case?

Comment: `NSMutableString` will be more efficient than creating `NSString` multiple times. And dot notation should be used only for properties.

Answer (score 0):

use `stringByAppendingFormat:` instead of `stringByAppendingString:`

I don't think `[mutableCopyOfProgram objectAtIndex:i]` is used when you use `stringByAppendingString:` so that would be what's unused.

a format is something like `@"%@", @"a string"` while a string is just `@"a string"`, so if you're going to use a format, make sure you use the proper method.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few stray parenthesis () and also should be using `stringByAppendingFormat:`

```
+ (NSString *)descriptionOfProgram:(id)program
{
    NSMutableArray *mutableCopyOfProgram = [program mutableCopy];
    NSString *descr = @"";
    for (int i=0; i<mutableCopyOfProgram.count; i++)
    {
        descr = [descr stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", [mutableCopyOfProgram objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    return descr;
}
```